# centralizar um menu nav

Tags: css, menu, nav-bar

Como posso fazer para centralizar esse menu?

```css
ul{
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
 display: block;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
}
#site-navigation {
 background-color: #111;
 border-top: 4px solid #289dcc;
}
li {
 float:left;
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item {
 background-color: #289dcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="colormag_style-css" href="files/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<body bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0px;">

<div align="center"><b style="font-size:50px; color:#FFF">LOGO</b></div>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix">
               <ul>

<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
</ul></div>                                    
                                                  
                   </div>
   </nav></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova o `float` e `position` de `li` e adicione `display: inline-block;` adicione um `padding: 0;` e `text-align: center;` ao `ul`

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
 display: block;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
}
#site-navigation {
 background-color: #111;
 border-top: 4px solid #289dcc;
}
li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item {
 background-color: #289dcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="colormag_style-css" href="files/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<body bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0px;">

<div align="center"><b style="font-size:50px; color:#FFF">LOGO</b></div>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix">
               <ul>

<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
</ul></div>                                    
                                                  
                   </div>
   </nav></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue o exemplo

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

ul{
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
 display: block;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
}
#site-navigation {
 background-color: #111;
 border-top: 4px solid #289dcc;
}
li {
 float:left;
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item {
 background-color: #289dcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0px;">

<div align="center"><b style="font-size:50px; color:#FFF">LOGO</b></div>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix">
               <ul>

<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
</ul></div>                                    
                                                  
                   </div>
   </nav></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deve-se tirar o efeito de lista na ul com margin e padding 0 também

```css
ul{
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#site-navigation {
 background-color: #111;
 border-top: 4px solid #289dcc;
}
li {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item {
 background-color: #289dcc;
}
```

```html
<div align="center"><b style="font-size:50px; color:#FFF">LOGO</b></div>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix">
               <ul>

<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
</ul>
</div>                                    
</nav>
```

use [Flexblox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Gente, muito obrigado deu certo, vocês são demais. Obrigado mesmo

Comment: @Guilherme quando sua pergunta é solucionada é legal escolher algumas das respostas como melhor no canto superior esquerdo da resposta, isso ajuda o site ficar mais organizado e outros usuários também :)

Answer (score 0):

A sua tag `li` no `CSS` esta setando `float: left`.(Retire isto)

Retire esta definição do `float` e como solução é facilitar sua manutenção de `CSS` junto à visualização de componentes, defina a classe de sua tag `ul`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no CSS acrescente os seguintes pontos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que isto já dará a você o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Faça essas pequenas mudanças:

```
.clearfix {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    /* float: left; */ /* REMOVA */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### Segue o Exemplo:

```css
.clearfix {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

#site-navigation {
  background-color: #111;
  border-top: 4px solid #289dcc;
}

li {
  display: inline=-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item {
  background-color: #289dcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="colormag_style-css" href="files/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<body bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0px;">

  <div align="center"><b style="font-size:50px; color:#FFF">LOGO</b></div>

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```